# Many-To-Many relationship Junction Table Question

Tags: sql, database, graphql, many-to-many

I have heard many-to-many relationships described as two one-to-many relationships but I don't really understand what that means/why that is necessary.

For example:

if you have

```
Class: ID, subject 

Student: ID, name 

Enrollment: ID, classID, StudentID
```

Here Enrollment is the junction/join table and allows for a many-to-many relationship between classes and enrollment.

for instance, if I want all the students enrolled in a class, I can take the class ID, find the enrollment tuples with the matching classID, and then map the corresponding studentID to a student.

What do I gain if I explicitly add:

```
Class: ID, subject, [Enrollment] 

Student: ID, name, [Enrollment]
```

this seems like it would just be restoring redundant information no? Since I can retrieve it without having it be an attribute under Class and Student.

**UPDATE**

Here is the specific example I an referring to -- It's graphQL through amplify with an explanation of how to manually create a many-to-many table

```
type Part @model {
  id: ID!
  description: String!  
  **inventories: [Inventory] @hasMany(indexName: "warehousesByPart", fields: ["id"])**
}

type Warehouse @model {
  id: ID!
  description: String!
  **inventories: [Inventory] @hasMany(indexName: "partsByWarehouse", fields: ["id"])**
}

type Inventory  @model {
    id: ID!
    warehouseId: ID! @index(name: "partsByWarehouse", sortKeyFields: ["partId"])
    partId: ID! @index(name: "warehousesByPart", sortKeyFields: ["warehouseId"])
    part: Part! @belongsTo(fields: ["partId"])
    warehouse: Warehouse! @belongsTo(fields: ["warehouseId"])
    inStock: Int!
}
```

notice how the analogues to class and student here (warehouse and part) both have hasMany relationships to the junction table of inventory (the analogue of enrollment). Why do you need to explicitly say that the warehouse and part table have many inventories?

Comment: It may lead to inconsistent database. You now are able to insert something to students enrollment, but it won't automatically appear in class enrollments etc.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, I guess my point is that without the two one-to-many relationships, there wouldn't be a students enrollment and a class enrollment. There would just be an enrollment table with every applicable pairing. Basically -- instead of using student.enrollments or whatever - you would just do SELECT * FROM enrollments WHERE enrollments.studentID == sutdent.id -- In short, why do you need relations form the two tables explicitly linking to the enrollment table, just having the junction table itself, without the others having [enrollment] is enough

Comment: Your question is unclear.  You wouldn't _gain_ anything, but you do lose everything.  Adding `enrollment` to each table is wrong.  The "many to many" relationship is expressed in the 3rd table.  The 3rd table contains the pairs of `(student_id, class_id)`.  There is no form of this with an extra column in the `student` table (and the `class` table), since the `student` table contains one unique row per `student` and that can't properly refer to more than one `class`.  That 3rd table contains two _"one to many"_ relationships.

Comment: Did you intend `[enrollment]` to be/represent some kind of array?  If so, don't do that.  That's not proper either, and is not what is meant by _two x one to many_ relationships.

Comment: Ah Okay that makes a bit more sense -- [enrollment] here refers to a one to many relationship as in the class has several enrollments and each student has several enrollments. I see this is a lot in examples, and I just added an updated one to the original question, but I don't get why this is necessary.

Comment: A field can (or, rather, should) only contain 1 value. If you have a m:m relationship you can’t model this with just the 2 tables and only have single values in a field. - therefore you have to use intersection tables. If you read up on data normalisation, specifically the 3rd normal form (3NF), this may make more sense